# javascript passing values dynamically to a method jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, methods

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function () {
    var vendor_id = $.urlParam('vendor_id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://testservice/testmenu",
        data: {
            vendor_id: vendor_id
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Could not get the menu : " + url);
        },
        success: function parseXml(xml) {
            var jsonData = $.parseJSON(xml);
            $(jsonData).each(function (index, post) {
                $(post).each(function (index, row) {
                    var finalString = [];
                    for(var index = 0; index < row.menu.length; index++) {
                        finalString.push('<div id="collapsibleMenu" data-mini="true" data-role="collapsible" data-inset = "true" data-content-theme="g">');
                        finalString.push('<h3>' + row.menu[index].category_name + '</h3>');
                        finalString.push('<ul id="menuDetails" data-role="listview">');
                        for(var j = 0; j < row.menu[index].products.length; j++) {
                            var output = ['<li data-icon="addToCart" id="addToCart"> <a href="javascript:test("+row.menu[index].products[j].prod_id")"><p>' + row.vendor_menu[index].products[j].prod_name + '</p><p> $' + Number(row.vendor_menu[index].products[j].price).toFixed(2) + '</p></a>' + '</li>'];
                            finalString.push(output);
                        }
                        finalString.push('</ul></div>');
                    }
                    $('#output').append(finalString.join(''));
                });
            });
            $('#output').trigger('create');
        }
    });
});

function test(prod_id) {
    alert("entered test " + prod_id);
    addToCart(prod_id, 1);
}
```

In the following code, where I am doing the following:

```
<a href="javascript:test("+row.menu[index].products[j].prod_id")">
```

This is obviously giving me an error. The point is, I need to pass the prod_id dynamically into the javascript test method. I am not sure how to do that. If I just call test without passing prod_id, it works great. Please help!

Comment: Tsk tsk, generating HTML with inline event listeners with string concatenation. The DOM exists for a reason, you know.

Comment: maybe a typo here, you miss + at the end: <a href="javascript:test("+row.menu[index].products[j].prod_id + ")">

Comment: You wrote all that nice jQuery code, and you could'nt be bothered to write a simple click function ?

Comment: @KhanhTo That will not work !!!

Comment: @adeneo I could have but I don't know how to use a specific id for each row. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Try removing the quotes in the argument.</strike>

I think I might have figured it out.
Try this.

```
<a href="javascript:test(\''+row.menu[index].products[j].prod_id+'\')">
```

Comment: `row`, `index`, and `j` are local to the anonymous function passed to `$(post).each` and cannot be accessed within an inline click handler.

Comment: You're getting warmer. You just need to remove the double quotes *directly* before and after the plusses.

Comment: @icktoofay when I do that, remove the double quotes, I get the following Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: @icktoofay :) Ok I do think I have the answer now.

Comment: I think what you had still had some quotes mixed up. I edited your answer to what I think is correct.

Comment: @icktoofay Yes thanks. That is what I actually meant. :) I had some lingering double quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, Quentin and @icktoofay It works now :) I will definitely look into jade

Comment: @mustaine: Or any of many other templating engines! If Jade doesn't suit your fancy, there are many other templating engines out there, almost all of which will simplify your code.

Comment: @mustaine You're welcome. I agree with looking into jade. You may want to try using HTML DOM with events too. DOM is certainly more complicated, but there are benefits.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the perfect reason to use a template engine. You might use a [Jade](http://www.jade-lang.com/) template like this:

```
for post in posts
    for row in post
        for menu in row.menu
            #collapsibleMenu(data-mini="true", data-role="collapsible", data-inset="true", data-content-theme="g")
                h3= menu.category_name
                ul#menuDetails(data-role="listview")
                    for product in menu.products
                        li#addToCart(data-icon="addToCart")
                            a(href="#", data-product-id=product.prod_id)
                                p= product.prod_name
                                p= '$' + Number(product.price).toFixed(2)
```

Then you can simplify your `$.ajax` call to:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#output').append(templateFunction(data));
    }
});
```

For the click event, use event delegation:

```
$('#output').on('click', 'a[data-product-id]', function() {
    addToCart(Number($(this).data('product-id')), 1);
});
```

Easy, yeah? *Now change all of your `id`s to classes, because `id`s must be unique and **yours aren't**!*

Comment: this looks very elegant but I have no idea how jade works or how to use it. Is there a learning curve? Is there something I can do to the original code snippet to get this done?

Comment: @mustaine: There's probably a learning curve but if you're doing lots of things like this then it'll probably pay off. Yes, there are modifications you can do to the original code to get it to work, but they're kind of ugly and I'd rather leave that to one of the other answerers.

Comment: @mustaine: I guess one thing you could do is insert the `data-product-id` attribute rather than the `href="javascript:..."` thing and then use the event delegation code I have, which does not require Jade.